# Tidying up css?

Tags: css

Is there any plugin or program that will scan an HTML document for unused classes and ids?

I have mozilla CSS plugin for firebug which tells me which styles are being used from my style sheet, but I wondered if there is the same kind of plugin that will check the HTML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) Firefox add-on for selecting unused selector.

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://unused-css.com/. Give it a try.